# Git pull from multiple remotes not working as expected

Tags: git, repository

I have found several similar questions to this but I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have a core project with multiple projects built on top of it, for the sake of this example lets say just one project, project A will be built on top of core.

So when originally creating project A. I would:

1)Create a new, empty repo for "project A" and initialise

2)Add "core" repo as a new remote and rename the remote to "core"

3)Pull from "core"

4)Build project A on top of it

5)Push back to origin (Project A repo)

Now one of my teammates want to work on project A so they pull project A from the repo, make some changes and commit.

So far so good...

But now I need to make a change to the core which should be rolled out to project A. So i pull the core, make the changes and then commit them and push back up.

At this point I would expect my team mate to be able to add core as a remote, pull in my changes from core and merge with project A.

But when they do this, the changes in the core are not coming through...

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong & how to fix it or how to find out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my case "`projectA`" and "`core`" both live at the same place within the directory tree. e.g "`projectA`" contains an app folder with a config file in it as does "`core`", changes to this config file in `projectA` should be merged with the same file in `core`.
> Sub-modules feel like the should be a child project (e.g a library within the main project). Is this still the right solution for me.

In that case, `projectA` and `core` would be two branches of the same repo, and not two different repos.

That doesn't prevent you to push different branches to **separate** repos (with a common history), one for `projectA`, and one for `core`. That avoid managing too many branches within one repo.

> At this point I would expect my team mate to be able to add `core` as a remote, pull in my changes from `core` and merge with `projectA`.
>
> But when they do this, the changes in the core are not coming through...

They should be able to do:

```
cd projectA
git checkout branch_of_ProjectA
git fetch core
git merge core/a_branch_of_core
```

---

Original answer

You need to declare `core` as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** within `ProjectA`

And when you make a change to `core` (with the sequence of commands you mention: pull, add, commit, push), you then need to go back one level up to `ProjectA`, add and commit the new SHA1 representing the new submodule '`core`' state.
And then push `ProjectA`.

When your colleague will pull `ProjectA`, a [`git submodule update`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) will update `core` to the relevant SHA1 within `ProjectA`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In my case "projectA" and "core" both live at the same place within the directory tree. e.g "projectA" contains an app folder with a config file in it as does "core", changes to this config file in projectA should be merged with the same file in core. Sub-modules feel like the should be a child project (e.g a library within the main project). Is this still the right solution for me.

Comment: @WebweaverD In that case, projectA and core would be two branches of the same repo, and not two different repos.

Comment: Is that the only way? The trouble is I'm creating lots of different types of unrelated projects off of core, they cant all live under the same repo, most of the projects and the core all have various dev, live and uat branches on them already. If i stick them all into one repo I could quickly end up with far too many branches to keep track of.

Comment: @WebweaverD Ok. I have rewritten my answer then.